# Active and focus class gets removed when someone clicks anywhere on website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using Bootstrap tabs, and I have three tabs and when each of them is clicked the active and focus class is being added to it so the users can know on which tab they are.

Now I added active and focus class to handle that but when someone clicks anywhere on the website the active and focus class is being removed. I have tried looking for an answer here, and literally tried everything from posts but I haven't had any luck.

I will upload images and code.

```css
  .nav>li>a:focus,
.nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #4272d7 !important;
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="" aria-expanded="false"><a class="bg-account active" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1" aria-expanded="true">My Account</a></li>
  <li><a class="bg-invite" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" aria-expanded="false">Referral</a></li>
  <li><a class="bg-lottery" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3" aria-expanded="false">Lottery Results</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Image 1:** When active and focus is on (this is how I would want it to be all the time when tab is active)

[image]

**Image 2:** This is when I click anywhere else on website, even tho im on the same tab active and focus class is being removed.

[image]

Can anyone please help me? Im dealing with this last two days and I havent had any luck.

Comment: can we have any code snippet on codepen or on fiddle

Comment: or what you can do, add debugger on `docoument.onclick` and try to find the element from where the event is triggred, `DEBUGG`  the code

Comment: @DupinderSingh — There's no JavaScript involved.

Answer (score -1):

`:focus` means "the element the user is interacting with".

If they click on an `<input>` then they aren't interacting with the `<a>` any more.

Implementing tabs using `:focus` is a hack that doesn't work well. The solution to your problem is to not do that. Use JavaScript instead.

Comment: Can you help me with javascript?